# Angular: unable to share object between two sibling directives

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

In my app, under a certain view I create two directives, `dir1` to loop through an array of objects, and `dir2` to show extra info, upon clicking\selecting something from `dir1`, so this basically means they are both on the same level. `dir1` gets the array from the view controller and renders the data. `dir2` suppose to get the data from `dir1` and I'm not really sure whats the best approach to achieve this. There are several possibilities:
 1. Upon selection on `dir1` use `emit` or `broadcast` services (through `$rootScope`?).
 2. Use a service.
 3. Require the parent controller (of the main view), update it from `dir1`, and somehow pass the object to `dir2`.

I tried using a `factory` service named `serv`, but I cant trigger the change in `dir2`, so I'm not sure this is a good solution.

This is how the main view is structured:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="parent">
        <dir1 character="person" ng-repeat="person in obj"></dir1>
    </div>
    <dir2></dir2>
</div>
```

`dir1` code:

```
angular.module("app").directive("dir1", function (serv) {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        templateUrl: "dirs/parent.html",
        scope:{
            character: "="
        },
        controller: function ($scope) {
        },
        link: function (scope,elem, attrs) {
            scope.getData = function (data) {
                // console.log(data);
                serv.setChar(data);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

`dir2` code:

```
angular.module("app").directive("dir2", function (serv) {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        templateUrl:"dirs/child.html",
        scope:{
            obj: "="
        },
        controller: function () {
            console.log("child ctrl")
        },
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            scope.obj = serv.char;
        }
    }
});
```

`serv` service code:

```
angular.module("app").factory("serv", [function () {
    var self = this;
    var char = {};

    return {
        setChar: function (character) {
            console.log("char set to: " + character);
            self.char = character;
        },
        getChar: function () {
            console.log("returned char: " + self.char);
            return self.char;
        }
    }
}]);<br>
```

EDIT: i forgot to add the `dir` template:

```
<p ng-click="getData(character)">
    {{character.name}}
</p>
```

EDIT2:
`dir2` template:

```
<span>name: {{obj.name}}</span><span>age:{{obj.age}}</span>
```

Comment: For now I don't see anything related to a click event in your code. And do you really need to use directives ? If they're just about displaying data you don't really need them.

Comment: @ValLeNain please see my edit, i forgot to add `dir1` template, it contains the `click` event. I dont really need to use `directives` here, but I want to learn how to use them, so this scenario is for that,

Comment: As you defined it, your `dir2` expects an `obj` property on the DOM element.

Comment: It was just a test, I didnt really know how to pass the object from `dir1` to `dir2`

Comment: and it compiles without errors ? Since you don't need to share this `obj` in your `dir2`, just write `scope: {}` in `dir2` definition. Are the console.log in the serv factory printing anything ?

Comment: Yes, no errors. The printing inside `serv` only shows that the data has been set, but the `getChar` never executes.

Comment: please add the template for dir2 and i can show you how to do it much more performant.

Comment: please see my edit, `dir2` template added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I make a new answer to work with directives.

The `console.log` inside `getChar` is never executed because you never call `getChar`. Which is fine. Instead you set `scope.obj` to `serv.char` in the second directive. The problem is, in you factory, you don't return this `char` property. You only return the `setChar` and `getChar` functions.

So either you return `char` from your factory (but it's not pretty cause you give direct access to the variable, and I guess you don't want to), or in the `link` function of `dir2` you create a watcher as below.

```
  scope.$watch(serv.getChar, function(newValue) {
    scope.obj = newValue;
  });
```

And so the `obj`property of `dir2` will be updated with the current person everytime it changes.

Comment: $watch not needed, aslo you should just edit your first answer instead of this second one and edit include your edits to which got you to this answer.

Comment: Thanks, `watch` did work. I thought there could be a "prettier" way to do this, like requiring the parent controller or so.

Answer (score 0):

(With you recent comment, I understand it's more to learn directives than an actual use case, my apologizes)

Your HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="parent">
        <div ng-click="selectPerson(person)" ng-repeat="person in obj"></div>
    </div>
    <div ng-if="selectedPerson != null">
    <!-- display whatever you want about the selected person --> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Inside your main controller

```
$scope.obj = []; /* this is your existing array of people */
$scope.selectedPerson = null;
$scope.selectPerson = function(person) {
  $scope.selectedPerson = person;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how you can extend you current code to share the data without having to make an extra service call and not add a $watch(which is expensive performance wise). Here is a working [pen](http://codepen.io/alphalink/pen/OWmXbj?editors=1010#0) to an example i have created.

```js
angular
  .module("app")
  .directive("dir2", function() {
    return {
      restrict: "E",
      templateUrl: "dirs/child.html",
      scope: {
        obj: "="
      },
      controller: function() {
        console.log("child ctrl");
      },
      link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
        //you should have the right data obj here
        // without having to make service call again or put a $watch.
        console.log(scope.obj);
      }
    };
  });
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="parent">
    <dir1 character="person" ng-repeat="person in obj"></dir1>
  </div>
  <dir2 obj="obj"></dir2>
</div>
```